# Recursively list number of files in all deep sub-directories

Tags: directory

I have searched for a solution to listing the number of files in each sub-directory recursively. There are many solutions that will give the number of files in each sub-directory of a given starting directory, but these seem to only list the sub-directory counts of the starting directory, and not recursively going down the tree structure for all sub-directories.

For example,

topdir1

sublevelA1        10 files

```
  sublevelA2    200 files  

     sublevelA3 600 files
```

sublevelB1        50 files

```
  sublevelB2    123 files  

     sublevelB3 357 files
```

The solutions that I have tried will only give me 2 lines saying sublevelA1 810 files and sublevelB1 530 files.

I would like a solution that gives me the 6 lines from above. Indentation is not required.

Comment: might be worth mentioning if a subfolder should count as file (of its superior folder), or mentioned separately?

Comment: For me, since accuracy down to the exact number of files is not required, it does not matter if a subfolder is counted as a file or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
find path/to/topdir1/ -type d -exec sh -c '
  d="$1"; set -- "$d"/*; printf "%s: %d files\n" "$d" "$#"
' sh {} \;
```

This will print full paths to the subdirectories - if you want the unqualified directory names, change `-exec` to `-execdir`. It will include directories in the counts of files.

An alternative might be to use a recursive shell function - note however that this will perform a depth-first search so the order of results may not be what you expect:

```
#!/bin/sh

_countrecurse() {
  local c=0;
  for f in "$1"/*; do
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then
      _countrecurse "$f";
    else
      c=$(($c+1))
    fi
  done
  printf '%s: %d files\n' "$1" "$c"
}

_countrecurse "$1"
```

with usage

```
./countrecurse path/to/topdir1/
```

This will *not* include directories in the file counts.

Comment: Thank you for the "find path/to/topdir1/...." answer. It did the job.